# Does a backend pagination in angular always refreshes the screen

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement pagination and sorting in angular without using Material framework.The problem I face is its refreshing the whole screen except the header and footer.Does a backendend sorting always cause a page refresh? How do I make sure the table gets reloaded not the whole page?

The data is loaded as shown below:

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
      this.examSummaryData = data['content'];
      this.totalRows = data['totalElements'];
      this.totalPages = data['totalPages'];
      this.pageNumber = data['number'] + 1;
      this.pageSize = data['size'];
      this.pageRows = data['numberOfElements'];
    },
    error => {
      this.errorMsg = error.error;
      console.log(this.errorMsg);
      console.error('There was an error in exam summary service!', error);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Hi you need to only change the table data source ? Have you tried this ?

Comment: There is no dataSource as such sort request goes through a backend call.

Comment: Angular will automatically redraw data when available (unless you have onPush), so that's the only thing you need to do. If you have onPush use `markForCheck()`.